# Unable to add worksheets to a xlsx file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am trying to export data by running dynamically generated SQLs and storing the data into dataframes which I eventually export into an excel sheet. However, through I am able to generate the different results by successfully running the dynamic sqls, I am not able to export it into different worksheets within the same excel file. It eventually overwrites the previous result with the last resultant data.

```
for func_name in df_data['FUNCTION_NAME']:
        sheet_name = func_name  
        sql = f"""select * from table({ev_dwh_name}.OVERDRAFT.""" + sheet_name + """())"""
        print(sql)                
        dft_tf_data = pd.read_sql(sql,sf_conn)
        print('dft_tf_data')  
        print(dft_tf_data)
        # dft.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
        
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+b', suffix='.xlsx', delete=False) as fp:
            #dft_tf_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
            print('Inside Temp File creation')
            temp_file = path + f'/fp.xlsx'
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(temp_file, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
            dft_tf_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
            writer.save()
    print(temp_file)
```

I am trying to achieve the below scenario.

1. Based on the FUNCTION_NAME, it should add a new sheet in the existing excel and then write the data from the query into the worksheet.
2. The final file should have all the worksheets.

Is there a way to do it. Please suggest.

Comment: xlsxwriter can only create xlsx files, it cannot edit existing files. Use either openpyxl to create/edit xlsx files (uses OOXML does not need Excel). Or XLwings which is like Excel VBA in Python so basically needs Windows and Excel installed.

Comment: I tried using openpyxl but it didnt work.

something like as per below.
pd.ExcelWriter(temp_file, engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:

Comment: to_excel will write to the first row unless you state otherwise so if if you are updating the sheet without indicating which row to start at each write will overwrite any previous write. The code sample I posted in this answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74646921/struggling-to-append-dataframe-to-existing-xlsx-file-in-python/74926641#74926641

Comment: Hi moken, I tried the below but it is throwing an error "No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp8v65cufp/fp.xlsx'.

 writer = pd.ExcelWriter(temp_file,mode = 'a', engine = 'openpyxl', if_sheet_exists = 'overlay')

But it works if I don't give mode=a and if_sheet_exists = 'overlay' parameters. Does openpyxl works differently with temporary files?

Answer (score 0):

I'd only expect a file not found that to happen once (first run) if fp.xlsx doesn't exist. fp.xlsx gets created on the line

```
writer=
```

if it doesn't exist and since the line is referencing that file it must exist or the file not found error will occur. Once it exists then there should be no problems.

I'm not sure of the reasoning of creating a temp xlsx file. I dont see why it would be needed and you dont appear to use it.

The following works fine for me, where fp.xlsx initially saved as a blank workbook before running the code.

```
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+b', suffix='.xlsx', delete=False) as fp:
    print('Inside Temp File creation')
    temp_file = path + f'/fp.xlsx'
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(temp_file,
                            mode='a',
                            if_sheet_exists='overlay',
                            engine='openpyxl')
    dft_tf_data.to_excel(writer,
                 sheet_name=sheet_name,
                 startrow=writer.sheets[sheet_name].max_row+2,
                 index=False)
    writer.save()
print(temp_file)
```